# Nodejs how to access callback variable outside the function?

Tags: node.js, callback

This is my code want to access callback variable newID outside calling-function. I want to insert bulk data into mongodb using batch with auto incremented id instead of default object

```
for (var i = 0; i < sizeOfResult; ++i) {
    var newKey = {};  //Main  json array 
    newKey = {
        date: result[i]['date'],  
        issue: result[i]['issue'],
        status: result[i]['status'] 
    };

    getNextSequenceValue("inventoryid",db, function(err, newID) {
        newKey["_id"] = newID;  <!-- try to add/assign callback variable(newID) into newKey  -->
    });
    console.log("newKey: %j", newKey);       <!-- but unable to get access callback variable(newID) here below-->
    batch.insert(newKey);
}
```

// This is my called function

```
function getNextSequenceValue(name,db,callback) {
    var ret = db.collection('counters_inv').findAndModify({ _id: name },null,{ $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } }, {new: true},
    function(err,doc )  {
        if(err){
        return callback(err)   // callback on error
    }
    callback(null, doc.value.sequence_value);  // callback on success

    });
}
```

Comment: Assign to the variable declared outside it

Answer (score 0):

Look at this code, you just need to put the variable outside and it works:

```
let i = 1

function functionwithcallback(callback) {
    console.log(i)
    i++
    callback(i)
}

for (let j = 1; j <= 10; j++) {
    functionwithcallback(() => {
        if (j == 10)
            console.log('done')
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the overall objective is, but the reason your `newKey` variable is not set correctly is because where it is being used has executed before the variable is set. In your example, your for loop is going to completely finish running kicking off a bunch of `getNextSequenceValue()` method calls that will eventually come back and run the callback code. **It does not wait on the getNextSequenceValue function to finish before continuing the loop**.

Solution: moving the `console.log()` and `batch.insert()` into the callback.

Here's an example that would execute in the correct order.

```
var keys = [];

for (var i = 0; i < sizeOfResult; ++i) {
    var newKey = {
         date: result[i]['date'],
         issue: result[i]['issue'],
         status: result[i]['status']
    };

    getNextSequenceValue("inventoryid", db, function(err, newID) {
         newKey["_id"] = newID;

         keys.push(newKey);

         if (keys.length === sizeOfResult) {
             console.log("keys: %j", keys);  
             batch.insertAll(keys); 
         }
    });
}   

function getNextSequenceValue(name, db, callback) {
    db.collection('counters_inv').findAndModify({ _id: name }, null, { $inc: { sequence_value: 1 } }, {new: true}, 
    function(err,doc) {
        if(err){
           return callback(err);
        }
        callback(null, doc.value.sequence_value);
     });
}
```

Comment: I want to access newKey outside the callback not inside callback. Just want to add **newID** generated from callback into **newKey**  json array and then use this **newKey** for bulk insert  outside callback.

Comment: I updated the answer to insert all the keys into the batch at the same time. Is this closer to what you are looking for? The logic is still in the callback because you need to wait for the results from the `getNextSequenceValue()` function.